# How do I concatenate input in java?

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to concatenate and trying to parse at the same time. I am right now making a excel like program where I can say a1 = "Hello" + "World" and in the cell  of A1 have it say HelloWorld. I just need to know how to parse the adding sign and connect those two words. Please tell me if you need more code to understand this, like the runner.

This is my parseInput class :

```
public class ParseInput {
    private static String inputs;
    static int col;
    private static int row;
    private static String operation;
    private static Value field;


    public static void parseInput(String input){
         //splits the input at each regular expression match. \w is used for letters and \d && \D for integers
        inputs = input;
        Scanner tokens = new Scanner(inputs);
        String none0 = tokens.next();
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        String none1 = tokens.next();
        operation = tokens.nextLine().substring(1);
        String[] holder =  new String[2];
        String regex = "(?<=[\\w&&\\D])(?=\\d)";   
        holder = none0.split(regex);
        row = Integer.parseInt(holder[1]);
        col = 0;
        int counter = -1;
        char temp = holder[0].charAt(0);
        char check = 'a';
        while(check <= temp){
            if(check == temp){
                col = counter +1;
            }
            counter++;
            check = (char) (check + 1);
        }
         System.out.println(col);
         System.out.println(row);
         System.out.println(operation);
         setField(Value.parseValue(operation));

         Spreadsheet.changeCell(row, col, field);

    }

    public static Value getField() {
        return field;
    }

    public static void setField(Value field) {
        ParseInput.field = field;
    }
}
```

Comment: A wise man once opined that using heavy dynamic machinery of regex for static content parsing is misguided.  He suggested building a lexer and then showed how to build a FSM-base done step by step: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HxaD_trXwRE - (this is not an answer but you should watch it when you have the time.)

Answer (score 2):

This is actually a pretty complicated problem unless you can constrain input to a very small subset of what Excel accepts. If not then you'll probably want to look into something like [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/). However, assuming the above input then you'll want to do something like:

1. Split the string on the equal sign into s1 and s2
2. Split s2 on the plus sign into s3 and s4.
3. Trim all the strings, remove the quotes around s3 and s4.
4. Concatenate s3 and s4 and assign to your datastore indexed by s1.

Depending on how complex your concatenation needs are you can either use string concatenation or a StringBuilder:

```
result = "" + s3 + s4; // string concatenation
result = new StringBuilder().append(s3).append(s4).toString(); // StringBuilder
```

Let me know if you have any questions about any of the steps detailed above.

Details on (1) above, assuming `input` is `a1 = "Hello" + "World"`:

```
String[] strings = input.split("=");
String s1 = strings[0].trim(); // a1
String s2 = strings[1].trim(); // "Hello" + "World"

strings = s2.split("+");
String s3 = strings[0].trim().replaceAll("^\"", "").replaceAll("\"$", "") // Hello
String s4 = strings[1].trim().replaceAll("^\"", "").replaceAll("\"$", ""); // World
String field = s3 + s4;

String colString = s1.replaceAll("[\\d]", ""); // a
String rowString = s1.replaceAll("[\\D]", ""); // 1
int col = colString.charAt(0) - 'a'; // 0
int row = Integer.parseInt(rowString);

Spreadsheet.changeCell(row, col, field);
```

Comment: What string on the equal sign are you talking about

Comment: I was assuming that `a1 = "Hello" + "World"` is the input to your program, so I was referring to that string, which would mean `s1` would be `a1` and `s2` would be `"Hello" + "World"`.

Comment: so using my code should I have to do something to input by any chance? And if i do how will I parse that. so that a1 is s1 and "Hello" + "World" is s2?

Comment: Thanks so I should use 
String[] strings = input.split("=");
String s1 = strings[0].trim(); // a1
String s2 = strings[1].trim(); // "Hello" + "World"

And should I put this under inputs = input?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to implement your custom grammar using a parser generator like [JavaCC](http://javacc.java.net/).

Here you can find a simple [tutorial](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-cooltools.html).

I believe this is the better solution because in this way you can handle every expression you need.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to  use all the classes you are using? To parse something like "a=b+c+d.." (assuming you are not trying to validate), easiest and possibly the most efficient way is to use [split API in Java lang String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)

Then join whatever is required using [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to design and implement a parser and an evaluator.  And before that, you need to design the language that your parser/evaluator is going to evaluate.

How to do it.

- If your language is really simple, you can get away with parsing it by hand, using something like StringTokenizer to do the tokenization,
- Otherwise, you are probably best off learning to use a Java "parser generator" such as JavaCC or ANTLR.

Either way, you need to do some background reading to understand all of the terminology.  You could start with Wikipedia and/or the tutorial material from one of the parser generators.  Alternatively, there are good textbooks on this topic.

Comment: Here this is my Value parse class:
public static Value parseValue(String val) {
  Value value = null;
  if (val.charAt(0) == '\"') {
   // String - need to remove enclosing quotes
   value = new TextValue(val.substring(1, val.length() - 1));

Comment: @user1321012 - I don't understand how your comment relates to what I said in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Abdullah said, if you really want to save every single ounce of memory you can, you should use the StringBuilder instead of the String concatenation. I believe i read somewhere before that the String concatenation make a new string object for each concatenations while the StringBuilder will add them all to a single String. Shouldn't matter too much though.

Answer (score 0):

In my early life I made an equation evaluator in your style. It cost me huge code and complexity, because of my unawareness about **Expression trees**. But now with this you will be able to add more capabilities to your parser easily and with native JAVA codes. You will get tons of example of using Expression Trees.